# Why does my code fail the hidden input test cases?

Tags: java, algorithm, user-input

This is the problem to be solved:

John is assigned a new task today. He is given an array A containing N integers. His task is to update all elements of array to some minimum value x , that is, `A[i] = x; 1 <= i <= N;` such that sum of this new array is strictly greater than the sum of the initial array. 
Note that x should be as minimum as possible such that the sum of the new array is greater than the sum of the initial array.

**Input Format:**
First line of input consists of an integer N denoting the number of elements in the array A.

Second line consists of N space separated integers denoting the array elements.

**Output Format:**
The only line of output consists of the value of x.

**Sample Input:**

5

12345

**Sample Output:**
4
**Explanation:**

Initial sum of array= 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15

When we update all elements to 4, sum of array = 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 = 20 which is greater than 15.

Note that if we had updated the array elements to 3, sum = 15 which is not greater than 15. So, 4 is the minimum value to which array elements need to be updated.

** ==> Here is my code. How can I improve it? or What is the problem in this code? **

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String []args){
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        int check=0, sum=0, biggest=0;
        int size=s.nextInt();

        if(size>=1 && size<=100000) {
            int[] arr=new int[size];
            for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
                int temp=s.nextInt();
                if(temp>=1 && temp<=1000) {
                    arr[i] = temp;
                    biggest=biggest > temp ? biggest:temp;
                    sum=sum+temp;
                }
                else break;
            }
            for(int i=1; i<biggest; i++){
                check=(size*i)>sum ? i:0;

            }
            System.out.print(check);

        }
        else System.err.print("Invalid input size");


    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this line necessary: `if(size>=1 && size<=100000) {`

Comment: This line finds the largest of the input values, which is not what you want: `biggest=biggest > temp ? biggest:temp;`

Comment: Besides a debugger you should also Google "hand execution" which will help you understand why your program doesn't work.

Comment: You wrote `A[i]=x;1<=i<=N` but if this is java shouldn't arrays be zero-based?

Comment: how do you know that `i<biggest` must be true? what if the array were `[1,1,1]`?

Comment: you are also missing a break out of the loop when check is assigned i, so it could be assigned larger i than necessary on subsequent loop iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue:**

```
for(int i=1; i<biggest; i++){
     check=(size*i)>sum ? i:0;
}
```

There are `2` problems with this, **hence** it doesn't work. They are as follows-

- `(size*i)>sum ? i` - The problem statement states that it needs minimum possible sum greater than sum of array of elements. Your code blindly assigns `i` to `check` without checking the **minimality**.
- `check=(size*i)>sum ? i`**:0** - So, even if you had come across some integer `previously`, you lost it because you assigned it to **0** if the condition is not satisfied.

I will share my idea of how would I go about this.

> Approach 1

- Sum all elements like you did.
- Now, take average of elements - sum / size of the array. Let's say we store it in a variable `average`.
- Print **average + 1** as your answer, as that is the value that could give you minimum possible sum > sum of array itself.

**Time Complexity:** O(n), where `n` is size of the array.

**Space Complexity:** O(1)

> Approach 2

- Sum all elements like you did.
- Calculate min and max for the array and store it in variables, say `mini` and `maxi`.
- Now, do a binary search between `mini` and `maxi` and keep checking the `minimum sum > sum` criteria.
- In this process, you will have variables like `low`, `mid` and `high`.

  ```
  low = mini,high = maxi
  while low <= high:
    mid = low + (high - low) / 2
    If mid * size <= sum, 
       low  = mid + 1
    else 
       high = mid - 1
  ```
- Now, print `low` as your answer.

Let `range` = `maxi` - `mini`.

**Time Complexity:** O(n) + O(log(range)) = O(n) asymptotically, where `n` is size of the array.

**Space Complexity:** O(1)

Comment: @user22226 It takes effort to help you. Please give me an update on whether it worked or didn't work. Where are you stuck?

Comment: Yes, I went through your approaches and they worked so well. Thankyou.

Comment: @user22226 Glad it helped :)

Comment: @user22226 if this solved your problem, can you please consider accepting it?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I completely followed what your attempt was, but there should be a pretty straightfoward solution. You know the size of the array and you can easily iterate through the array to get the value of the elements stored in it. All you need to do to find your min x is to take sumOfArray/size of array and then add one to the result to make your result higher.

In your example 15/5=3. 3+1 = 4 so that's your answer. If the numbers summed to 43, 43/5 = 8 r 3, so your answer is 9 (9*5=45). Etc.

Answer (score 0):

When trying some other test cases, then the results are wrong. Try:

**Input:**

```
5
1 1 1 1 5
```

**Expected Output:** `2` **Actual Output:** `4`

and

**Input:**

```
5
5 5 5 5 5
```

**Expected Output:** `6` **Actual Output:** `0`

Comment: It should return the value which is less than the max. value in your array. So your expected outputs are bit wrong.